# Crop the center region

Tags: video, premiere

I want to crop the center region of a video while exporting it for YouTube upload. It is 360 x 360 pixels. I don't know what is the best format for this task and when I try MPEG2 and set the frame width and height to 360 the output is blurry. What should I do instead? I'm using Adobe Premiere 4.2.1.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crop the video in a new sequence in Premiere and then export it using Youtube's [standard encoding settings](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it's not a solution, because there is no sequence preset with matching frame size, so there will be black bars.

Comment: @Beginner - you can either make a sequence with a custom frame size or you can simply scale the video to show only the part you want with it interpolated to a higher frame size.  To do a custom size, ignore the presets tab, go to the settings tab, choose Custom as the Editing Mode and enter your resolution, frame rate and pixel aspect manually.  You can also save it as your own preset if you will need it regularly.